# UIAlertController acting weirdly on iPad

Tags: ios, swift

I am presenting a `UIAlertViewController` from inside a `UIViewController` that is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. This is embedded in a `UITabBarController`. I present it when someone presses on a certain cell inside a `UICollectionView`.

On the iPad I have to specify the `sourceView` and `sourceRect` for the `popoverPresentationController` of the alert view controller. For this I have made the `sourceView` to be the cell, and the `sourceRect` to be the bounds of the cell. Here's my code:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = cell
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = cell.bounds
...
self.present(alertController, animated: true)
```

This works when I display it and dismiss it twice, but on the third time the popover moves to be in the top left corner of the screen.

After the popover is dismissed for the first time, I get a warning: `<_UIPopoverBackgroundVisualEffectView 0x7ffe21c19e00> is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1.`.

Also there is a thin 1 or 2px line going through the centre of the popover. I am testing this on the iPad Air 2 with iOS 10.3.1. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems it's something to do with getting the cell from the collection view that's causing the issue. Instead I've passed the exact `UIButton` in the collection view to my function and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Do action", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Action 1", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        // Handle action-1
    }))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Action 2", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        // Handle action-2
    }))
    let popOver = ac.popoverPresentationController
    popOver?.sourceView = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    popOver?.sourceRect = (collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.bounds)!
    popOver?.permittedArrowDirections = .up
    self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```